# Finding BsonDocuments where a specific fields value is within a List<ValueType>?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two collections in my MongoDB database. `Collection1` has a field of type `Guid` (well `string` really) named `Col2DocRef` which references the `_id` of documents in `Collection2`.

I currently have a `List<Guid>` representing `_id`s of documents in `Collection2`. I would like to find all documents in `Collection1` where the field `Col2DocRef` is equal to any value in the `List<Guid>`.

**Is this the proper way to do this by using `AnyIn`?**

```
List<Guid> guids = ... // Creating by searching in Collection2 and deserializing
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn("Col2DocRef", guids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `FindAsync()` passing the filter like below assuming that those collection have corresponding strongly typed POCO in your application interface.

```
List<Guid> guids = ... // Creating by searching in Collection2 and deserializing
var collection = db.GetCollection<Collection1>("Collection1");
var result = collection.FindAsync(col => guids.Contains(col.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I have abstracted my calls to get documents by providing a method that is passed an enumeration of my collections, a `FilterDefinition`, and a `SortDefinition`. This has worked well in all other instances. I was specifically asking about using the `AnyIn` function of the `FilterDefinition`. Though I see that this answer could work if I do need to make it do so.